# possible to use anchor tag but not on a link in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uiwebview

I want to have a UIWebView that uses an anchor tag but not to a link.

Like the following:

```
<div name='my-anchor'>here is the target</div>
```

using:

```
/url#my-anchor
```

Is this possible? Is there a better way to handle this?

Saw you could do this

```
var x=document.getElementById('mi1566');
x.scrollIntoView();
```

but having mixed results esp at bottom of page.

-thx

Comment: You'll want to use `id='my-anchor'` rather than `name`. What do you mean by _mixed results esp at bottom of page_? Navigating to an anchor will not scroll a page beyond the bottom of the content.

Comment: well, I would suspect that something has written something like a negative margin value or maybe a highlighting plugin to emphasize the content or something. If anything looking possibly for either a technical OR a non-technical sol'n.  Re, the id, would you suggest using the id and the javascript sol'n?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to trigger the scroll event? A click on an element? or are you wanting to scroll via `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`?

Comment: I was thinking rather than using a url anchor just passing in the id via url like /url/12 for id=12  and inserting dynamically into page.

Comment: [The id attribute may be used to create an anchor at the start tag of any element (including the A element)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3) which can be linked to with an `a` element (`<a href=#foo">foo</a>` - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wQkjy/)) or focused with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) suggests that the **name** attribute is only used with the **a** anchor. The [**div**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp) tag does not contain *(nor support)* the name attribute.

What I have typically done in the past is this:

```
<a name="my-anchor">&nbsp;</a>
<div class='mydiv'>here is the target</div>
```

[image]

Here is the **div** information as **MDN** sees it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/div

Comment: Please link to more credible source like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/link) rather than [w3schools](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: @steveax were you not an "invited expert" to W3s HTML5 working group? Is w3 not that credible?

Comment: Either way, instead of down voting an answer, post one since you think this is an invalid answer.

Comment: So to comment on the soln't, that's what I was thinking but it looks really ugly. Like an 'a' without a href?